# How should I test for the existence of a table and fail a script if the table does not exist?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is what I came up with. Seems very hacky but it is what someone in the Snowflake forums suggested. Surely there's a better way.

```
use database baz;

-- divide by zero hack to check the existence of a table and bail if it isn't present
-- improvements to this welcome, snow sql doesn't have a clean way to bail like raiseerror
select 1/(select count(*) from information_schema.tables
    where table_schema = 'foo'
  and  table_name = 'bar')
```

This script is intended to run after a setup script. This is here to make sure the required tables exist after the script has been run.

Comment: why would you do this? what are you trying to achieve? can you better explain the scenario so we can give a reasonable answer. Either way you getting an error, so do the simplest one which is just run the query and handle the failure.

Comment: "This script is intended to run after a setup script" - that's the justification, do you need further information? Seems clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is that as for today Snowflake SQL does not support control structures(IF/WHILE/FOR/SWITCH/TRY/CATCH). It will probably change in the future but as for now you could use Java Script stored procedures.

> [Overview of Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html)
>
> Snowflake stored procedures use JavaScript and, in most cases, SQL:
>
> - **JavaScript provides the control structures (branching and looping).**
> - SQL is executed by calling functions in a JavaScript API.

The pseudocode:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc(...)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
  var tab_exists = `select count(*) from information_schema.tables
    where table_schema ILIKE 'foo'
      and table_name ILIKE 'bar'`;

  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: tab_exists} );
  var resultSet = stmt.execute();
  resultSet.next();

  var result = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);

  if (result > 0){ 
 
    ...
  }
  else {
    return  'table not found';
  };

$$;


-- invocation
use database baz;
call my_proc();
```

### EDIT:

Using **[Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html)** is much easier to write such scripts:

```
DECLARE
   my_exception EXCEPTION(-20001, 'table_not_found');
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM information_schema.tables
              WHERE table_schema ILIKE 'PUBLIC'
                AND table_name ILIKE 'NON_EXISTING_TAB')) 
   THEN
     RETURN 'TABLE_EXISTS';
  ELSE
     --RETURN 'TABLE_NOT_FOUND';
     RAISE my_exception;
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing for table existence by expecting an exception if the table doesn't exist, you could just run a select on the table.

This will generate an exception if the table doesn't exist:

```sql
select count(*)
from schema.table
```

The proposal in the question to look on the information_schema is cool if you need a query that doesn't generate an exception, but once you divide by 0, it's clear that you were asking for one.

Comment: Stopping script execution by raising exception is in my opinion tricky. If transacation is involved then at least [TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#transaction-abort-on-error) should be set. I am looking forward for a moment when we will have proper control flow structures in SQL and such operation could be done in unnamed block. Sort of: `BEGIN IF EXISTS(...) THEN .... ELSE ... END END`. It is really important piece if there is a need  to write fully idempotent SQL code.